# I have a csv file, i am using pandas to import the csv. i need to read through each row and only print if my value is 1 for that row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, spyder

For eg:

My csv:

I have my students who take different courses, I want to know how many students take which course.

```
    stud1 stud2 stud3 stud4 stud5 
c1    1     0     0     0     0  
c2    0     1     0     0     0
c3    0     0     1     1     0
c4    1     0     0     0     1 
c5    0     0     0     0     1
```

I want the output as :

```
course [1,1,2,2,1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/belKZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this example.

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("mycsv")
number = 0
for index in dataframe.indexs:
    for  i in range(len(dataframe.loc[index].values)):
        if(dataframe.loc[index].values[i] =='fox'):
            number += 1
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda to solve this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1]])
df.apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis = 1).values
```

[output]:

```
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```